# What does the "preparing" step do when I upload a video on some website with my iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, data-transfer

I have an iPhone 12 mini, which runs iOS 15. When I upload a 5GB video on some website such as https://www.filemail.com/, https://www.datatransfer.com/, https://www.sendbig.com/ or https://wetransfer.com/, iOS spends about one minute "preparing" the video. What does the "preparing" step do?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

From what I read on [Reddit](https://redd.it/175el65), the preparation step may involve converting the video.

> Probably converting the video from HEVC to a more widely compatible format (likely AVC). When selecting a video in the image picker, there's an Options setting to configure this. Reddit user:[nooneinpar7](https://beta.reddit.com/user/nooneinpar7)